# Помощь с создание таблиц в базе данных SQL Server

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

У нас есть две таблицы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связь один ко многим.
Вычисляемый столбец "Стоиость", понятно как сделать. И как связь сделать тоже. А вот как сделать в первой таблице "Общая сумма заказа" и "Список позиций заказа" для меня загадка уже как несколько недель...

Comment: То, что "заказ характеризуется неким полем", ещё не значит, что это поле должно в таблице существовать. Указанные поля - как раз из этой песни. Значения этих показателей есть агрегированные значения, которые должны вычисляться в запросе либо представлении на основе имеющихся в таблицах данных. Кстати, это же касается и поля "Стоимость". К слову, есть и поля, которые в структуре должны быть, но не указаны в списке. Например, в таблице позиций должно быть поле с идентификатором заказа (правда, в данном случае поле формально указано - но не там, где надо).

Comment: Но если нечем заняться - то заводи соотв. поля и обновляй их из триггеров. Хотя я бы настоятельно не советовал... читайте теорию по термину "переопределённые данные".

Comment: По сути из этого мне нужно сделать приложение на C# что бы работать с этой таблицей. Добавлять заказы, удалять, редактировать. Я уже битые недели сижу над ней и всё никак не могу родить что то нормальное. Если работать только с одной таблицей, тут проблем никаких нету. А вот связанные. Беда

Comment: Я рекомендую изучить нормализацию БД(первых 3х форм будет достаточно) и сделать 2 нормальных таблицы, а денормализованные данные показывать в представления, которое объединяет данных этих таблиц с подсчётом общих сумм